# Algorithm to sort 2d-points in increasing order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, computer-science

I have to write a pseudo code for an algorithm which sort n 2D points which are randomly distributed within the unit circle. I need to sort them by their distance from the origin 0,0 ( by Increasing Eucledian distance to the circle's origin).

So I think they should be as a 2D array or a Map:

A = { (0.3 , 0.4) , (0.5 , 0.7) , (0.2 , 0.1) , (0.32 , 0.9) }

So here n = 4, we have 4 2D points.

First I thought to calculate the distance from origin (0,0) so (d = sqrt( (A[i].x)^2 + (A[i].y)^2) ) for each point, creating a 1-D array which can be easily sorted using any sorting algorithm, but then I found out that it can be sorted but I cannot have the 2D array sorted in the end, since in the end I just know the d(distance).

Can someone give me a hint on how can I start or explain to me the basic points which I need to go through in order to sorts shuch a system?

Comment: What are the sorting criteria, that is, what exactly are you asked to do? For example, what is the desired result on your sample array?

Comment: What kind of 2D coordinate - polar or cartesian? And what is the purpose of the sorting? You might be sorting on X then Y - or you might be "sorting" then so you can trace the convex hull - or you might want to sort them in some other order.

Comment: I need to sort them by their distance from the origin 0,0 ( by Increasing Eucledian distance to the circle's origin). I am very sorry but I totally forgot to say that in the problem above, thanks!

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int, point>> data`

Comment: @MooingDuck I guess that std::sort() will sort the vector by either X or Y not by the distance of the point from the origin !?

Comment: @Dan: `std::sort` will sort the vector by the first element in the pair, and only where two elements have the same `.first`, it will subsort by the the second element of the pair.

Comment: (Hint: a spelling checker might flag `Eucledian` and `shuch`.)

Answer (score 1):

This question basically boils down to a normal sorting problem. You just need to use the appropriate comparison function.

In c++ for example you could achieve this by storing the x and y values inside a struct and then overloading the `<` operator.

```
struct coor
{
        float x;
        float y;

        bool operator < (const coor &lhs)
        {
                return (x * x + y * y < lhs.x * lhs.x + lhs.y * lhs.y);
        }
};
```

and then `std::sort` will work on a vector of coor structs.

Comment: One up for *not* computing the Euclidean distance. If computing squares still cost much more than comparison (those times are gone by decades), one could do without computing the former whenever the sum of absolute coordinate values ([1-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm)) of one comparand exceeds that of the other by half.

Comment: How can I do this on Pseudo-Code, can you explain me a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can store points as a `vector` of `pairs`. And use build-in `sort` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool my_comp(const pair<float, float>& point1, const pair<float, float>& point2)
{
    return point1.first*point1.first + point1.second*point1.second < point2.first*point2.first + point2.second*point2.second;
}

int main()
{
    vector< pair<float, float> > points;

    points.push_back( make_pair(3.1, 4.1) );
    points.push_back( make_pair(0.9, 0.8) );
    points.push_back( make_pair(1.0, 1.0) );

    sort(points.begin(), points.end(), my_comp);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        cout<<points[i].first<<" "<<points[i].second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to program in python, same goes for here. Use array of arrays and use build-in sort function:

```
def my_comp(point1):
    return point1[0]*point1[0] + point1[1]*point1[1]

points = [ [3.1, 4.1], [0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0] ]
points.sort(key=my_comp)
print(points)
```

Comment: Yes but I still cannot see how can I do this in pseudo-code? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Dan, I am not sure if I could convert 3-line code into pseudo-code properly. It would not make any sense, at least for me..